# How to perform batch Inference using a Yolo v8 model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, yolov8

I have a question regarding the batch Inference in [YOLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection#Methods) v8.
I am using a pre-trained YOLO V8 model (huge model).
The inference time to predict on single image on a RTX3060-Ti GPU is about 18 ms, I was trying the batch prediction on 64 images which is about 1152 ms...which doesn't gives me any time advantage.
As previously, I was using the [YOLO 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection#Methods) model the time for batch inference, and there was around 600 ms for 64 images which gave me a time advantage over the individual inference.

I have attached the code for reference.

What is wrong or how do I do batch inference in YOLO v8?

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import time

camera_list = []

for camera in range(64):
    camera_list.append(cv2.VideoCapture(r"E:\Python_Project\demo_video.mp4"))

model = YOLO(".\Models\yolov8x.pt")

while True:
    camera_frames = []
    for camera in camera_list:
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        # frame = cv2.resize(frame, ())
        camera_frames.append(frame)
        if not(ret):
            break
    # print(camera_frames)
    start_time = time.time()
    results = model.predict(source=camera_frames,show=True)
        # print(results)
    # print(results)
    print(time.time()-start_time)

    # print(results)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Video memory usage when doing prediction on a single frame? From What you describbe (huge model) it sounds like it actually cannot do batch processing of many frames at once and actually splits your 64 frame input into very small batches that still fit in VRAM

Comment: Yes,the Video memory usage is about 30% for single frame inference and about 80% for a 64 frames inferences

Comment: as you said, it splits 64 frame into multiple batches what is the minimum batch size for that